# Selenium webDriver - wait for cookies and local db cookies in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I use selenium to get cookies and local db cookies in java.

if I use following code to wait the side will be ready I don't get all the cookies:

```
webDriverWait.until(webDriver -> "complete".equals((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver.executeScript("return document.readyState")))
```

I saw that if I wait enough of time eventually I will get all the cookies (regular cookies and userData cookies that saved in local db).

Is there a way to use webDriverWait to wait until all the cookies will be load?

Answer (score 0):

You never know if your client loaded all the possible cookies. Because if you have asynchronous UI each new request might add new cookie or modify existing one.

So the better, more reliable and "proper"  approach would be to first of all know which cookies exactly you expect to have. Say you keep the names in `Set<String> cookieNames`.

Then your wait would look like:

```java
webDriverWait.until(
        webDriver -> {
            Set<Cookie> cookies = webDriver.manage().getCookies();
            return cookies.size() == cookieNames.size() &&
                    cookies.stream().allMatch(cookie -> cookieNames.contains(cookie.getName()));
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

or if your frontend is using Angular, you can wait until this script is true (meaning the site is fully loaded) and then can continue with your script for fetching cookies:

```
return window.getAllAngularTestabilities().findIndex(x => !x.isStable()) === -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced many cases where `document.readyState` returns "complete" before the page has visibly been loaded, let alone cookies after loggin in.

To check if a cookie exists in the session:

```
driver.manage().getCookieNamed("cookieName");
```

Problem is that the `Cookie` object returned is **nullable**.

Options:

1. try/catch - try to check if the cookie exists
   - catch `NullPointerException` and try again
2. create a retryable method that accepts another returning method (Supplier) and evaluates the boolean expression (Predicate) you want met.   *recommended

For example:

```
  public <T> boolean retryable(Supplier<T> method, Predicate<T> condition, int retries) {
    for (int i = 0; i < retries; i++) {
      T methodReturnValue = method.get();
      if (!condition.test(methodReturnValue) || methodReturnValue == null) {
        // Todo: sleep / wait / try again immediately
      } else {
          return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

**Just implicitly waiting without retrying is not recommended as it can waste execution time that builds up for each test using this wait**